# how to print it in next line in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import datetime 
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now() 
print ("Current date and time is:", currentTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Output is:

> Current date and time is: 2016-10-18 22:31:21

I want it to be:- without using another print statement may be /n which is not working:-

> Current date and time is: 
>   2016-10-18 22:31:21

Help?

Comment: The new line character is '\n', not '/n'.

Comment: @Aurora0001 great minds, huh?

Comment: This should not be downvoted.  The question was clear enough and included code.  Questioners should not be punished for being beginners.

Comment: The downvote tooltip is: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". In my opinion, research effort would have shown that new lines are `\n`, and it is unlikely to be useful to anyone else because it is a simple typographical problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass whatever separator you like with the *sep* keyword `sep="\n"`:

```
 In [1]: import datetime
   ...: currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
   ...: print ("Current date and time is:", currentTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M
   ...: :%S"),sep="\n")
   ...: 
Current date and time is:
2016-10-18 18:21:25
```

If you wanted multiple newlines:

```
In [4]: print ("Current date and time is:", currentTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M
   ...: :%S"), sep="\n" * 3)
Current date and time is:


2016-10-18 18:21:25
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a newline character (`'\n'`) to your print:

```
print("Current date and time is:\n", currentTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

## EDIT

As **@StevenRumbalski** points out, it would be better to use string concatenation with `+`:

```
print("Current date and time is:\n" + currentTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

to avoid the indentation that results from my previous code.

Comment: That indents the second line by one character.  To fix that either add the two strings to make a single string or pass the argument `sep=''`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks for pointing that out; I didn't notice that. I usually don't concatenate strings with `,` so I am not used to this method.

Comment: @RajPathak glad it worked for you. Also, see my edit for how to remove the extra indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Newline character is `\n` not `/n`